# Using a macro to create and pull info from a new sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[google-apps-script] I am trying to run a macro which creates a new sheet and then returns specific values of that new sheet to the main dash where the macro button is displayed. (Example: !DashboardA1=!NewSheetA1) The problem I am running into is that the macro is not using the references in the new sheet that was just created, but rather the sheet that was used when the macro was recorded. (Example: !DashboardA1=!OldSheetA1 , Instead of !DashboardA1=!NewSheetA1). Is there a way for Google Sheets to use the newly created sheet rather than the old sheet to pull the information from within a macro without having to manually link the cells?

Comment: Your question would have probably already been answered had you taken the time to provide your code with your question. Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

### Sample how to

- create a new sheet,
- set a value in a new sheet
- copy this vlaue to the original sheet:

```
function myFunction(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var newSheet = ss.insertSheet();
  newSheet.getRange("A1").setValue("foo");
  newSheet.getRange("A1").copyTo(activeSheet.getRange("A2"));
  }
```